# Given $1/x<E$, how to get an inequality of the form $x>$ something?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$$ \frac{1}{x} <E $$
$E, x$ always positive.

How can I get to expression like this:

$ x > \text{something} $

in one stage? If it's not possible in one stage (although this is what my teacher did) other answers are also good.

Comment: You also need to know about the sign of $x$.  As it stands there is no lower bound on $x$ (it could be $-10^n$ for any $n$, for example).

Comment: @lulu,  i checked what my teacher did, x is also positive

Comment: I figured, but you should edit the question to reflect that.  Not sure what you mean by "one stage"...you can multiply both sides by $\frac xE$.  That's positive so it preserves the inequality.  Is that one stage?

Comment: thanks @lulu , maybe this is what my teacher did :) the result if you multiple by x/E is the same result like the teacher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplication by a (strictly) positive quantity conserves the (strict) inequality. So if $x>0$,

$$x\dfrac{1}{x}<Ex$$

Similarly for $E>0$, $1/E<0$ so $$\dfrac{1}{E}<x$$

Note that multiplication by a negative quantity reverses the sign of the inequality: $3>2$ but $-1\times 3< -1\times 2$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x>0$, then $$\frac{1}{x}<E\implies 1 <xE\implies \frac{1}{E}<x$$
which is the same as $x>\frac{1}{E}.$

In other words $something = \frac{1}{E}.$

Answer (score 1):

You said that x > 0, so then we can simply do this:

$$\frac{1}{x} * x < E * x$$

$$1 * \frac{1}{E} < Ex * \frac{1}{E}$$

$$\frac{1}{E} < x$$

Which is the same as $x > \frac{1}{E}$

Answer (score -4):

$$E>0 \\\frac{1}{x}<E\\\frac{1}{x}-E<0\\\frac{1-Ex}{x}<0\\x=0,\space x=\frac{1}{E}>0$$
[image]
$$x<0 \space \cup x \geq \frac{1}{E}$$